# colleague who doesn't want ES6 JavaScript Next

Tags: project-management, productivity

How do i deal with a colleague who doesn't want to bring the new version of JavaScript into projects.

Current scenario:

- Team Size: 3.
- Team members are the decision makers.
- Using ES6 the only benefit removal of Middleman process and use webpack and babel
- and write better code

Comment: How backward compatible is everything?  Have you done full sociability testing with all existing applications?  It sounds like your colleague is being suitably professional and risk averse.  Once you've done your testing, then you can look at upgrading.

Comment: Per Dean Inge: "There are two kinds of fool. One says 'this is old, and therefore good.' The other says 'this is new, and therefore better.'" Do you have a good reason why you must upgrade, and take the risk of unknown new problems? Does s/he have a good reason for not upgrading? You may both be right, or wrong, for different reasons.

Comment: I have used new version of JS in few of my personal projects and all works fine. Since Im using Babel to transpile the code into ES5.

I think I asked in wrong community.

Comment: What is your work setup? Just the two of you? Who is responsible for the software stack in your company? Who pays for it? This question misses a lot of information.

Comment: @STEEL I can see why he wouldnt want to, lots of Problems can come with it, also could you add the size of your Team? internal or external products/Clients? Reason why your colleague does not want to upgrade?

Comment: @RaoulMensink team size is 3.

Comment: You need an approach other than "Why can't these fools see that this is better".  or "Because I say so!".  **show** don't tell.

Comment: With the question written from a technical perspective, you're on the wrong site. We've also covered how to argue for technical/logistical improvements/updates before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a genuine benefit to using ECMAscript 6 over 5 in the applications you're building? Does this benefit actually bring any real cost-benefit/time-benefit over continuing to use ECMAscript 5?

From your colleagues perspective, there needs to be a good reason to do this. If you're working in a team, its very likely not everyone is familiar with the latest version of ECMAscript. Is it really worth expecting everyone to know the new features of this version without having any real added benefit? I honestly don't think so.

My suggestion would be to give your colleague evidence that this will improve your product. These improvements needs to be significant enough that they are a real benefit and not just saving a line of code in your application.

Comment: the only benefit is for developers, write better code.

Comment: @STEEL But that's the thing, new isn't always better when you're working with an already huge code base. If you want to convince someone, give them some sample where you take a snippet and improve it using ECMAScript 6. This might raise some eyebrows and get noticed by people.

Comment: using ES6 we write less, do more. Thats all I can tell them

Comment: @STEEL **Evidence it.** Don't just tell them, **show them**. Take a module/function/whatever it is you're writing. Make it quicker or smaller using ES6 features. Otherwise, there is no justifiable reason to changeover.

Comment: @Dandy I downvoted, dont ask questions to the op in answers, add a comment instead.

Comment: @RaoulMensink With respect, my questions were to show STEEL what he should be asking himself to put himself in his colleagues shoes. I don't think you're entirely wrong, but I do think a downvote was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convince them anyway. Tell them how important it is to keep up to date with the latest technology. Also, a good thing would be to see if using ES6 is actually useful or not. If it's not, then don't bother too much about it. If it is, then tell them exactly why. For example:

> If you use ES6, you can do X much better and features like Y and Z will be available which will make anything much better.